# To find the xor of 2 numbers a & b after making the binary expression of smaller one equal to the bigger one by trailing zeroes

Tags: c++, binary, dynamic-memory-allocation, stringstream, bitwise-xor

Input:
The first line of the input contains integer T denoting the number of test cases. For each test case, there are two integer inputs a & b.

Output:
For each test case, the output is the integer displaying the  XOR of a & b after making them of equal lengths.

Constraints:
1<=T<=100
1<=a,b<=107

Example:
Input:
4
2 6
3 10
5 24
1 20
Output:
2
6
12
4

Explanation:
1. The binary representation of 2 is 10 and of 6 is 110. As the length of "10" is smaller, so add a '0' to it making it "100', to make the length of binary representations equal. XOR of 100 and 110 gives 010 which is 2.

my code is

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cmath>
#include <sstream>
#include <cstring>
#include <string>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
int cases, binary[100];
cin>>cases;

int *result = new int[cases];
int j;
for(j=0; j<cases; j++){

    stringstream ss[3];
    for(int k=0; k<2; k++)
    {
        int n;
        cin>>n;
        int temp=n, i=0, len;
        while(temp > 0){
            binary[i] = temp%2;
            temp /= 2;
            i++;
        }
        len = i;

        string str ;
        for(int i=0; i<len; ++i){
            stringstream ss;
            ss << binary[(len-1)-i];
            str += ss.str() ;
        }
        ss[k] << str;
    }

    string str1 = ss[0].str(), str2 = ss[1].str();
    int len = (str1.length() > str2.length()) ? str1.length() : str2.length() ;

    if(str1.length() < (unsigned)len){
     int diff = len - str1.length();
     for(int i=0; i<diff; ++i){
            str1 += '0';
        }
    }
    else if(str2.length() < (unsigned)len){
      int diff = len - str2.length();
     for(int i=0; i<diff; ++i){
            str2 += '0';
        }
    }

    string str3 = str1;
    for(int i=0; i<len; ++i){
         if(str1[i]==str2[i]){
            str3[i]='0';
        }else   str3[i]='1';
    }
    int length = str3.length(), val=0;
    for(int i=0, m=length-1; i<length, m>=0; ++i,--m){
        if(str3[i] == '1'){
                val += pow(2, m);
         }
    }
    result[j] = val;
}

for(int i=0; i<cases; i++){
    cout<<result[i]<<endl;
   }

return 0;
}
```

i think i made it more lengthy and complex, how to make it simple and concise.

Comment: You can accompish the length equalization by simple shifting and masking. No need for an array, more strings, etc.

Comment: using `std::bitset` might make it easier to work with, you would easily be able to look at individual bits, shift them, and xor them together

Comment: also if you have working code and are looking for suggestions, please post to https://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Comment: Ok..i will from now on

Comment: But bitset requires size of the number that it will take pre-requistely..bitset <length> x( )

Answer (score 0):

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main() {

    unsigned T;
    cin >> T;

    unsigned a, b;
    for (unsigned i=0; i<T; ++i) {

        cin >> a >> b;

        if (a < b) 
            swap(a, b);

        unsigned shift = 0;

        if (a > b) {
            while(!(a & 0x40)) {
                a <<= 1;
                b <<= 1;
                ++shift;
            }

            while(!(b & 0x40))
                b <<= 1;
            }

        cout << ((a ^ b) >> shift) << ' ';
    }

    return 0;
}
```

And some explanations:

- although A and B are both less than 107 and could fit into single byte each, we should use int to handle it to gaurantee that cin numbers parsing would work correctly;
- as xor gives the same result independently of arguments order we could swap A and B if pleased - and it is useful for us to have A always not less than B;
- since A and B are less then 107 we could be sure beforehand that their most significant bit (8th) will always be zero, with any possible value entered, and so initial per-bit left shifts ("<<= 1") could be performed until the 7th bit become equal to 1 (tested by applying 0x40 mask to A/B value and checking if the result it non-zero) instead of 8th; after that the B will still remain less than A;
- zero padding of b is perfomed by further left-shifting of b (if necessary) until, in turn, its 7th bit becomes "1" too;
- to get rid of the effects of initial left-shifting of both arguments we should either right-shift both of them back to the same amount of bits (" >> shift") before xoring or, that have the same effect, right-shift the result of their xor before cout-ing it - which is more covenient (to me).